# Architecture: Avoiding duplicate model/modelview code in MVC/Entity Framework Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to the whole ASP world and I'm getting my feet wet by building a C# MVC3/EF4 project.  I'm finding it hard to keep from duplicating a bunch of code in my models and view models.  Consider an object Foo.  I need to do the following things with Foo:

1. Store records of type Foo in my database.
2. Allow users to lookup records of an individual Foo (pass instances of Foo to a view).
3. Allow users to create new instances of Foo (pass instances of Foo to a form).

Let's say I also have a type Bar.  A Bar contains a list of Foos.  There are two requirements here:

1. Users can view a list of Bars.
2. When the user clicks on a specific Bar, it shows all of its Foos.

So, a sketch of my basic objects look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    string FooName;
    int Id;
}

class Bar
{
    List<Foo> FooList;
    int Id;
    string Baz;
}
```

But when I start thinking about the different views, it begins to get messy:

- The views shouldn't have any write access to any of the data members.
- There's one view that takes a list of Bars but doesn't care about Bar.FooList.  Let's say I also want to be good about resource management and close the DbContext as soon as possible (i.e. after the object is in memory but before I render the view).  If I just pass it a list of Bars and the designer tries to access the FooList by mistake, we'll get a runtime error.  Yuck!

Ok fine, I just create a distinct ViewModel for each view that has read only datamembers, no problem.

- But both the database model and the form models will need to have DataAnnotations attached which say which fields are required, max length of the strings, etc.  If I create separate form models and database models then I end up having to duplicate all these annotations.  Yuck!

So, that's my architectural dilemma:  I want to have succinct view models which restrict the views only to reading the data they are supposed to access.  I want to avoid repeating data annotations all over the place.  And I want to be able to aggressively free my DB resources as soon as possible.  What's the best way to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is do NOT use data annotations in your EF entity classes. Instead, try out the fluent API. It keeps persistence concerns out of the model classes themselves. You can even define the modelbuilder stuff in an entirely different library.

As for having duplicate properties, properties are cheap:

```
public string MyProp { get; set; }
```

Not a lot of code, and you may begin to see, the viewmodels and entities need not always be exact duplicates of each other. For example, what if you want to apply [HiddenInput] to a viewmodel, to get it to render as `<input type="hidden" />`? Would you apply that to the entity? Why? It belongs in the viewmodel (the namespace is even System.Web.Mvc, not System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations).

As far as duplicating error messages during validation (if you validate the MVC and EF layers separately), you can use resx resources.

As far as freeing db resources, let EF manage that. I find it's best to keep a single DbContext instance per HttpContext. You can open it up using a factory, an OnActionExecuting action filter, Application_BeginRequest, with an IoC container, or whatever. Then dispose context during OnResultExecued, Application_EndRequest, etc. Keeps things simple.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I agree something like HiddenInput doesn't belong on the entity.  But what about attributes that apply both to the database and to the form, like MaxLength?

Comment: I use the fluent API, so I would never put the maxlength attribute on the entity class. Instead I would call `.HasMaxLength(int)` on the entity property during OnModelCreating. I no longer use dataannotations on viewmodels either, and now opt for FluentValidation instead. However, you can keep the length properties consistent between these 2 layers by having them both get their int values from a common shared file with something like `public const int MyPropertyLength = 140;`. Then both EF and MVC can reference that const in attributes, method calls, messages, whatever.

Comment: I don't see how using the EF Fluent API helps you with DRY? You'd still have to define `MaxLength` (for example) on both the EF model and the ViewModel, otherwise the model state won't be automatically populated with the right errors to send back to the user. I'm grappling with the same challenge here. I know of `BindAttribute` but am loath do use something string based.